# How to submit a form on web using delphi

Tags: html, delphi

How can I create and post form like the form below ***Using Delphi7***?

```
   <Form method="post" action="www.TestAddress.com/TestPage.php">
     <input Type="Text" name="TestName" value="SomeValue" />
     <input Type="Submit" value="Submit" />
   </Form>
```

Comment: Please provide a description of what you are trying to do. As it now stands your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @TomBrunberg I have a website with a database, one of the database item is customer debt, value of this debt is calculating by a program developed by Delphi, I want to post this value to website's database by clicking a button and the customer see that value by entering his/her ID and password. Indeed After post, I'll get value in html and I'll store it at database with php commands.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Delphi ships with Indy pre-installed (though Delphi 7 is very old, so consider [upgrading its Indy to a modern version](http://www.indyproject.org/sockets/Docs/Indy10Installation.aspx)), which has a `TIdHTTP` component. It's `Post()` method has overloaded versions that are meant for submitting webforms, for example:

```
Params := TStringList.Create;
try
  Params.Add('TestName=...');

  IdHTTP1.Request.Username := ...;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password := ...;
  // set other properties as needed...

  IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.TestAddress.com/TestPage.php', Params);
finally
  Params.Free;
end;
```

Depending on the server's requirements, you may have to request the HTML of the webform first to get any cookies associated with it so they can then be sent back to the server as part of the webform submission. Or you may need to set the `Referer` request header to the URL if the webform that is being submitted:

```
// make sure TIdHTTP.AllowCookies is set to True beforehand...
IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.TestAddress.com/WebForm.php');

Params := TStringList.Create;
try
  Params.Add('TestName=...');

  IdHTTP1.Request.Username := ...;
  IdHTTP1.Request.Password := ...;
  // set other properties as needed...
  IdHTTP1.Request.Referer := 'http://www.TestAddress.com/WebForm.php';

  IdHTTP1.Post('http://www.TestAddress.com/TestPage.php', Params);
finally
  Params.Free;
end;
```